# Why constant defined in an interface cannot be accessed without Interface name in the implemented class?

Tags: c#, constants, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

We have the interface and the implementing class:

```
pubic interface IStackContainer {
    const string DefaultStack = "default";
}

public class StackContainer<T> : MyBaseStackContainer<T>, IStackContainer{
    protected  internal string Stack {
        get { return Get(nameof(Stack), IInterface.DefaultStack); } //works fine
        set { Set(nameof(Stack), DefaultStack, value); }   //doesn't exist in the current context, why?
    }
}
```

Why can't I access the constant in the StackContainer without "IInterface."?

PS: my purpose here is to place the const  somewhere  instead of StackContainer in order to have easy access to it.
If it was defined in the StackContainer I could use it like this: StackContainer.DefaultStack, but it isn't a good decision, I think.

Comment: These classes are not inherited one from another. In my case if IStackContainer was an a class it would work fine

Comment: @Progman That's a different problem, and is not related

Comment: It's the same rule over and again though - if you want to reference a constant in *any* other type, no matter what inheritance/implementation relationship may exist, you always have to reference it via the type's name.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... unless it's in a base class. Since a base class is similar to an interface, it's not unreasonable to expect that they behave the same way here

Comment: Well, if you want to "inherit" from a **pubic** interface, you need to wait several months before you can safely access any constant members!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trivially, because that's what the spec says.

I suspect this is to avoid the problems which come with multiple inheritance. Consider:

```
interface IA
{
    public const string DefaultStack = "default";
}

interface IB
{
}

class C : IA, IB
{
}

// Imagine this is allowed:
string stack = C.DefaultStack;
```

Imagine even that `IA` and `IB` are in different assemblies.

It's now a breaking change to add `const string DefaultStack = "..."` to `IB`, because that would make `C.DefaultStack` ambiguous. That effectively means that adding *any* const field to an interface is a breaking change, because that might conflict with a field of the same name in some other interface, and break some type which implements both of those interfaces somewhere.